# Extending controller in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, controllers

Here is my app structure:

```
/application
/config
/library
  /Foo
    /Controler.php
/module
  /User
    /config
    /src
      /Bar
        /Controler
          /BarController.php
/public
/vendor
/init_autoloader.php
```

The Controler.php file...

```
namespace Foo_Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;

class Foo_Controller extends AbstractRestfulController {
  protected $foo;

  public function getFoo()
  {
    return "foooo";
  }

  function __construct() 
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $foo = $this->getFoo();
  }
}
```

The BarController.php...

```
namespace Bar\Controler;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Foo_Controller\Foo_Controller;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class BarController extends Foo_Controller {
.
..
....
}
```

Added the path /library folder in the init_autoloader.php

```
  $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $zf2Path = 'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library';
  $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
  $loader->add('Julia', 'library'); // added the library folder

  if (!class_exists('Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or     define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
}
```

I get an error 500 with the following:
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Foo_Controller\Foo_Controller' not found in /application/module/Bar/src/Bar/Controller/BarController.php on line #

I really don't know what to do now. I have been searching the internet for some time now for the correct way to extend a controller class in Zend Frazmework 2, but i can't seem to grasp it!

What am i doing wrong in the app?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you set this out slightly differently. Would really make more sense to create your own custom module which you can load into any project with directory structure like:

/zf2-MyCustomModule
  /src
    /MyCustomModule
      /Controller
        /Abstract
          /MyAbstractController.php

namespace for MyAbstractController.php would be - MyCustomModule\Controller\Abstract

If it is specific to the project then why not just add

/Abstract
  /MyAbstractController.php

to the User Module Controller dir.

but seems like what you have done is pretty much right you would just need to update namespace in Foo_Controller.php to:

```
namespace Julia\Foo\Controller;
```

not

```
namespace Foo_Controller;
```

Though I have never used the method you are using so am not 100% sure.

I would add a new local config to /config/autoload/

like /config/autoload/namespaces.global.php

```
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
     'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
         'namespaces' => array(
             'Julia' => __DIR__ . '/Library',
         ),
     )
));
```

then your namespace should still be Julia\Foo\Controller;

Comment: Yea changing the namespace should work. I've extended controllers in ZF2 with no issues.